# Is there a way to do a reverse "code generation" in jooq?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I use jooq (version 3.5.3) in one of my projects and I am quite happy with it. Now I came across the situation that it would be nice to check if a table in the database is available and, if that's not the case, create it.

That would come in handy when I'm installing my software on a new system and I could just take care of table creation automatically.

My initial idea was to use:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
for (Table<?> t : Public.PUBLIC.getTables()) {
    create.createTable(t);
}
```

However, it does nothing since it lacks the `.execute()`. But that is apparently only possible if at least one `.column()` is added. If I do

```
create.createTable(t).column("foo", SQLDataType.INTEGER).execute();
```

it works, and creates the table, but (naturally) only with one column called foo.

**So, the question is:** Is there a lazy way to just create the table in the database that it fits to the generated code, or do I have to use a more manual approach for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason and motivation for jOOQ to originally support DDL statements is precisely what you have in mind, and is described in this feature request here:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3160

In fact, the motivation is slightly different. While jOOQ doesn't encourage you use its DDL for actual schema creation (because of the lack of support for storage clauses, and other vendor-specific features), it will be useful nonetheless for generating test schemas that are somewhat equivalent to the original production schema.

As of jOOQ 3.6, the supported DDL statements are still far from complete to help you re-generate your schema, which is why #3160 is still not implemented. You will have to write some glue code yourself, e.g. (still incomplete, but to give you an idea):

```
for (Table<?> t : Public.PUBLIC.getTables()) {
    CreateTableAsStep<?> a = create.createTable(t);
    CreateTableColumnStep b = null;

    for (Field<?> f : t.fields())
        if (b == null)
            b = a.column(f, f.getDataType());
        else
            b = b.column(f, f.getDataType());

    b.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And keep up the good work, it really helps a lot!